# Why are ATTiny so expensive compared to ESP modules compared to features they offer?

Tags: attiny

I was looking for a cheap MCU solution for a project, apart from being compact, ATTiny doesn't seem to provide much value. I was hoping it is cheaper but nope, They are mostly above 1.5 USD in any shop. Whereas I can easily get an ESP module for a comparable price if not cheaper, added WiFi, and optionally Bluetooth, and they are not too huge for my use cases. Am I missing something?

Comment: $1.50 is very cheap

Comment: I gave a comparison with an ESP module, which can be bought for around the same price, with a hell lot of more features and speed and everything superior.

Comment: manufacturer pricing questions are not on topic here ... prices are set to whatever the buyers will pay

Comment: Understandable why the question might seem out of scope for the community, but I really struggled to get an answer to the question. And The first answer actually solved my problem, good that it got in before the question was closed. Hope this thread will help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get ATTINYs for much less than $1.50.

For example, right now you can order the ATTINY202 from stock in single unit quantiles from Microchip for $0.48 each. They drop to $0.35 each at 5K units (also in stock).

https://www.microchipdirect.com/product/search/all/ATTINY202

If you are really price sensitive then you can sometimes get the smaller ATTINYs for even less when buying in reels at a time, but you have to shop around.

Anytime you pick a part you have to trade-off purchase price, availability (both now and in the future), and suitability. The AVR parts can often be the best choice- but all depends on what you are using it for!

Comment: Thanks @bigjosh that was really helpful. I was looking at older versions like attiny85/84 etc which is probably expensive because they are no more in production. I started looking for new ones and ended up in Digikey website where I could find lots of 0, 1 and 2 series ATTinys. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Just FYI if other folks find themselves here from Google looking for attiny85 alternatives: As far as I can tell, the newer chips (the 0, 1, and 2 series) aren't available in PDIP packaging, so they may not be an appropriate replacement for the attiny85 if someone were looking for a breadboard-compatible device.